# How to plot a conditional bar chart

Tags: r, if-statement, count, conditional-statements, bar-chart

I am analysing the pokemon dataset on R. I would like to create a bar chart about legendary pokemons in each generation.
The dataset looks like this:

```
| Generation| Is_legendary  |
| 5         | 1             |
| 2         | 0             |
```

Is_legendary:  0 or 1 (1 means it is a legendary pokemon, 0 means it is not.)

I assume we have to embed a `countif` function?

Thanks a lot for any input

Comment: Could you show more data, or if you are using R, then use `dput`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution!

```
d.RB_Project <- read.csv(file = "pokemon_v2.csv", header = TRUE)

df_legendary_count <- aggregate(is_legendary ~ generation, d.RB_Project,sum)

barplot(df_legendary_count$is_legendary, main='Count of Legendary Pokemons',
        xlab = 'Generation',names.arg = c('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'))
```